# What is the maximum number of distinct keys a PS/2 or a USB keyboard can have that Windows 10 would understand as unique keys?

Tags: windows, windows-10, keyboard, ps2

I've been looking for information on how to expand a keyboard to bind additional keys to various commands, without resorting to key combinations (like <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F12</kbd>). [From what I've found](https://wiki.osdev.org/PS/2_Keyboard), it seems like in theory a PS/2 keyboard can operate 256 different signals, but not all of them are available for sending normal key presses, because some bytes are reserved for the PS/2 keyboard operation data. Maybe USB keyboards have solved this issue, but then the question remains of whether a modern version of Windows will understand all these key signals.

On [MSDN page listing virtual key codes](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/inputdev/virtual-key-codes) some of the keys are listed as "unassigned", "reserved" or "OEM-specific". What I'd like to know, is how many distinct byte codes for keys Windows would understand if somehow they were sent to the system, either via AutoHotKey type software or via a custom arduino-based USB or PS/2 keyboard with all those extra keys, without any OS modifications like editing keyboard drivers, and whether there are some limitations to specific keys, like for example some of them are modifier keys, or cannot be used in combinations with other keys.

Comment: related - https://askubuntu.com/questions/884724/how-many-keyboard-key-combinations-are-possible-in-ubuntu "each key has a potential of 63 unique combinations with 6 modifiers, 64 if you include it on it's own." Some structures can also recognise 'chords' using two alphanumeric keys &/or mouse button presses. idk if windows or AHK can do this. Mac can with 3rd party support. Also see http://xahlee.info/kbd/how_many_keyboard_shortcuts.html

Comment: Your question should be about scan codes not virtual keys..

Comment: https://download.microsoft.com/download/1/6/1/161ba512-40e2-4cc9-843a-923143f3456c/translate.pdf

Comment: @Mark I'm not sure what the right term is for a type of key that Windows understands natively as a signal passed to it from a keyboard device, so I didn't specify.

Comment: The link you posted did specify VKeys. However you can only send virtual keys to Windows programmatically..